# Is there a way to calculate coverage of i18n - ie to find strings that are not wrapped?

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

We are currently in the process of wrapping strings in order to make our product available for i18n. We're using Django translation on the back end and Jed.js on the front end, and it would be good to have some sort of coverage test we could run to find missing strings.

I can't find anything even vaguely related to doing this - I assume at least partly because it would be quite a complex process. But it also seems unbelievable that no-one has yet produced such a tool.